# string.format - Commas as decimal separator

Tags: c#, string-formatting

Given the input `123.45`, I'm trying to get the output `123,45` via `String.Format`.

Because of the system I'm working in, the actual format strings (e.g. `{0:0.00}`) are saved in a config file and transformed later down the pipeline.

Editing the config file to add a new format is "safe" and I can get this through quite quickly. Editing the actual parser later down the line is "risky" so will need a more significant QA resource and I need to avoid this.

As a result, some caveats:

- I only have access to `string.Format(pattern, input)`. No overloads.
- I cannot send a localisation. I know that if I send `string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE"), "{0:0.00}", 123.45)` then I've got what I need. But I cannot pass the localisation.

So can it be done?
Is there any format I can pass to `string.Format` which will transform `123.45` into `123,45`?

Comment: why do not you try to replace "." with "," using Replace method

Comment: @Ehsan.Saradar All I have access to is a config file where I specify the `format` input to a `string.Format`. I need to specify something that will work in this file. I already have a working solution if I can make code changes later down the line ;-)

Comment: At the point of calling string.Format, what type is the value? Has it already been turned into a double?  `string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE"), "{0:0.00}", "123.45")` doesn't work (note the last parameter being passed as a string).

Comment: @RichardIrons Yes - it's been turned into a `float`.

Comment: if you are saving these values to the .config file.. then why not create a method that reads the key, value and check if that value `.Contains(".")` then do the formatting and use it that way regardless of the Globalization..

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't think there's a way to do this. Unfortunately the system you're working with just isn't flexible enough; there are many ways to achieve this and you've just been restricted by a previous developer so you can't use any of them.

Comment: @MethodMan It's still a change to the codebase and it will cause a full regression cycle in QA.

Comment: @RichardIrons Yeah I spent a while looking at this before posting and came to the same conclusion, that it can't be done. No worries. I'll have to just go for the codebase changes.

Comment: so what's the problem with the Regression test.. either way you will need to make a code change is what it sounds like.. sounds like this was a poorly thought out development plan from the get go.. in all due respect..

Comment: @MethodMan Just trying to avoid the time overhead. I came to StackOverflow with a specific question, I know there's alternatives and wasn't looking for a critique of a codebase, just an answer to a pretty specific question.

Comment: it's not about `critique` we are asking specific questions, because it seems that someone dropped the ball during your `QA` testing phase.. these types of things should have been pickup there as well as in Unit Testing / Test Development

Answer (score 1):

If you can you multiply the input by 100 then the following should work:

```
double input = 123.45;
string pattern = "{0:###\\,##}";

var result = String.Format(pattern, input*100);
```

Comment: Awesome thinking outside the box so I upvoted, though sadly I cannot multiply by 100. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just for the fun of it :)

```
        double value =123.45;
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:#0.00}\b\b\b,", value));
```

This of course only works when there is a cursor, like in the console, otherwise the backspace control characters have no effect.

Sorry, but i can't think of a real way in accomplishing this.